# nzRouteLabelFn does not work with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, ngx-translate

I'm using an auto breadcrumbs module and I need to translate the titles with my TranslateService, what's the way to use it when I declare the constants of the Routes in other component and the layout component where I show the breadcrumb.

I have tried with:

```
<nz-breadcrumb [nzAutoGenerate]="true" [nzRouteLabel]="'breadcrumbI18nKey'" [nzRouteLabelFn]="translateFn">
</nz-breadcrumb>
```

//In component

```
translateFn = (key:string) => this.translateService.instant(key);
```

//In Route

```
{
  path: '',        
  data: {
    breadcrumbI18nKey: 'i18n.name'
  }
}
```

But the translateFn function does not find the key.

Comment: Do other keys work? Is the desired value undefined? What does it display? One thing to keep in mind is that your `TranslationService` instance may not have been initialized yet hence `instant` might not yield any results. There is an async method `get` you could try as well (keep in mind that it returns an `Observable`).

Comment: The error I have is "Error: Parameter "key" required at TranslateService.instant"

Comment: The problem is that nzRouteLabelFn does not support observable, I have to pass it a string

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz of how does yo make it work the translation with the autogenerate breadcrumb from ng-zorro, please

Answer (score 0):

Add `""` prefix key work!
**Like here:**
[image]

Comment: Please try for [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).